# Regex test causes 'Too much recursion' error in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, firefox, bugzilla

I've been implementing validations for the input using Javascript and Regex.
I found interesting (at least I think so) behavior with one particular Regex.

```js
/([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,})/gi
```

This Regex is for the URL input value validation.

Validation is triggered on user input event with some timeout like that:

```html
<input onInput={(event) => this.inputChangedHandler(event)}} />
```

And the validation part:

```js
...

if (!this.urlPattern.test(this.inputValue)) { // Here I am testing URL regex mentioned above
      this.isValid = false;
      this.validationErrorMessage = 'Please, check URL';
}

...
```

And in that step I am getting 'Too much recursion error'. In Chrome and Firefox.
All other regexes I used in a same way to validate other input types (like email, number, etc etc) working perfectly well.

**So my questions are:**

Is that behavior expected for large regexes ?
Is my regex wrong in some way ?

I have tried this regex to match the string value like this:

```js
this.inputValue.match(this.urlPattern)
```

Which worked for me well too.

I found some bug report here:
[bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=616491)

*Large number of groups in regex causes too-much-recursion crash (YARR)*

Seems like really similar to my issue.

Comment: You validate a string with a regex having a `g` flag? Please remove it, it makes no sense. Validation also implies checking if the whole string matches the pattern, and your pattern misses `^` at the start and `$` at the end. These are the points you should consider before checking the pattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you, I will change the regex

Comment: your regex can be  simplify like this  "/((https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?[a-zA-Z\d][a-zA-Z\d-]+[a-zA-Z\d]\.[^\s]{2,})/i"
same as your regex but smaller , can be fix the recursion

Comment: If `^` and `$` are really necessary then there is even no need "enhancinating" the rest of the pattern.

Comment: However, do you guys have any idea about the error I mentioned ?

Comment: Yes, your pattern alternatives (most of them) can match at the same location in the string, and `g` makes it search at every position inside the string. This may cause catastrophic backtracking if the string is huge. So, the solution is either make the alternatives match only at separate positions, or make it match the whole string, or both.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew hmmmm, sounds like makes sense, I will try to rewrite the pattern and see if issue fixed :)

Comment: You may also explain what you are trying to achieve and receive a definitive answer.

Comment: "*Seems like really similar to my issue.*" - how come it is your issue? You only have 2 non-quantified groups in your pattern.